# Mule parameters in host http:request-config not working correctly

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I am trying to make an inbound endpoint to consume a REST API, it works if I don't add the filter parameters but when I do it doesn't work.

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration"  host="mywebsite.org/api/countries?display=[name,id]&amp;filter[name]=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.string']" port="433" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" >
        <http:basic-authentication username="user" password="123"/>
    </http:request-config>


<flow name="CountryByValue">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" path=countryByValue" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.string']" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="GET" doc:name="REST API">
        </http:request>
        <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

In my loggers I can see the query string is really there

```
INFO  2015-04-21 11:21:25,389 [[panierv2].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: /getCountryByValue?Canada
INFO  2015-04-21 11:21:25,411 [[panierv2].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Canada
```

But in the end it doesn't return me the right thing :

```
<api xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<countries>
</countries>
</api>
```

If I do it directly in the browser with the link it works :

mywebsite.org/api/countries?display=[name,id]&filter[name]=Canada

I get this :

```
<api xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<countries>
<country>
<id>
<![CDATA[ 4 ]]>
</id>
<name>
<language id="2" xlink:href="sdfg">
<![CDATA[ Canada ]]>
</language>
<language id="3" xlink:href="sdfg">
<![CDATA[ Canada ]]>
</language>
</name>
</country>
</countries>
</api>
```

The problem seems to be in the & in the host. But I can't seem to make it work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add those query parameters in the request element, not the request-config.

It should look something like this:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration"  host="mywebsite.org" basePath="api" port="443" protocol="HTTPS" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" >
    <http:basic-authentication username="user" password="123"/>
</http:request-config>
...
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/countries" method="GET" doc:name="REST API">
    <http:request-builder>
        <http:query-param paramName="display" value="[name,id]" />
        <http:query-param paramName="filter[name]" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.string']" />
    </http:request-builder>
</http:request>
```

I made the host end at api and then set the rest as path in the request since that way it will be easier to reuse.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello and thank you for taking the time to help me. It is strange I now get an error from the api's side : `code`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<api xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<errors>
<error>
<message>
<![CDATA[Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors.]]>
</message>
</error>
</errors>
</api>`code`

Comment: Is there a way to log my outgoing complete URL to see if it's the exact same thing that in the browser? To see if the error isn't on the api's side?

Comment: I think that is coming in a future version of mule. You could however user something like wireshark to sniff the requests on your network.

Comment: Hello I have been able to show errors on the api side but the problem seems to be coming from Mule...Here's the error `<![CDATA[
Resource of type ":433" does not exists. Did you mean: "tags"? The full list is: "addresses", "carriers", "cart_rules", "carts", "categories", "combinations", "configurations", "contacts", "content_management_system", "countries"
]]>` Apparently what Mule is sending is `http://mywebsite.org/api/:433` because when I enter this in a browser it gives me the same error. It seems like it only adds the port I set, if I remove it, it gives the same error with 80. Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried putting the port in `http:request` but I get the same error.

Comment: Right, I didn't consider that. The problem is that if the host has the path included then the port will be added in a way that results in an invalid URI. I'll modify the above example.

Comment: Done. I added the "api" part to the basePath attribute. You could also move it to the request element's path attribute: ```path="/api/countries"```.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping, I tried both ways and Mule gives me null (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException). I tried removing the port and it gives me the website (not the api) with an error 404 without the css. This is really strange and I don't know what to do should I create another post as this one is getting quite large?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75953/discussion-between-afelisatti-and-paperbag-writer).